# Cannot read property '0' of undefined - javascript error?

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down menu, and when I select the 'All' option, it gives me this error on the console:

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at n.$scope.onSearchByChanged (http://localhost:8080/js/jenkinsVersion/directives/assignment-filter.js:70:81)

So, I went to my script, function, line 70,character 81 :

```
    $scope.onSearchByChanged = function () {
            if ($scope.filter.list.searchBy == 'DEPARTMENT_CODE' && !$scope.filterScope.departments) {
                $scope.loadDepartments();
            } else if ($scope.filter.list.searchBy != 'DEPARTMENT_CODE') {
                $scope.filter.list.departmentId = 0;
            }
            if ($scope.filter.list.searchBy == 'GROUP' && !$scope.filterScope.editorGroups) {
                $scope.loadEditorGroups();
            } else if ($scope.filter.list.searchBy != 'GROUP') {
                $scope.filter.list.groupId = $scope.filterScope.editorGroups[0].id; //line 70
            }
            $scope.clearFilter('text');
        };
        if ($scope.filter.list.searchBy == 'GROUP' && !$scope.filterScope.editorGroups) {
            $scope.loadEditorGroups();
        }
        if ($scope.filter.list.searchBy == 'DEPARTMENT_CODE' && !$scope.filterScope.departments) {
            $scope.loadDepartments();
        }
        $scope.isStatusSelected = function (status) {
            return _.indexOf($scope.filter.list.talentAssignmentStatuses, status) > -1;
        };
        $scope.selectTalentAssignmentStatus = function (status) {
            $scope.clearFilter('text');
            if ($scope.isStatusSelected(status)) {
                _.remove($scope.filter.list.talentAssignmentStatuses, function (el) {
                    return status == el;
                });
            } else {
                $scope.filter.list.talentAssignmentStatuses.push(status);
            }
        };
```

here is the loadEditorGroups function :

```
$scope.loadEditorGroups = function () {
            Reference.getEditorGroups($scope, function (response) {
                $scope.filterScope.editorGroups = response.list;
                if ($scope.filterScope.editorGroups.length > 0) {
                    $scope.filter.list.groupId =   $scope.filterScope.editorGroups[0].id
                }
            });
        };
```

I'm still learning JS. Why is this error being thrown?  When I change the value of the item I want to retrieve from that editorGroups list it just gives me the same error but with the corresponding number.  Your help would be appreciated, please let me know if I can supply further information. Thank you!

Comment: Probably `$scope.filterScope.editorGroups` is an empty array, so attempting to read the first array item yields undefined.

Comment: 70:81 means line 70, _column_ 81 by the way; line 81 isn't relevant.

Comment: `$scope.filterScope.editorGroups` is `undefined`. Can't access its element  `'0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for this `if-else` block is *probably* wrong:

```
if ($scope.filter.list.searchBy == 'GROUP' && !$scope.filterScope.editorGroups) {
    $scope.loadEditorGroups();
} else if ($scope.filter.list.searchBy != 'GROUP') {
    $scope.filter.list.groupId = $scope.filterScope.editorGroups[0].id; //line 70
}
```

The program will enter the `else if` block when **both**:

- the `if` condition is `false`, that is: `($scope.filter.list.searchBy == 'GROUP' && !$scope.filterScope.editorGroups) == false`
- the `else if` condition is `true`, that is: `($scope.filter.list.searchBy != 'GROUP') == true`

We can take these two statements and simplify them:

1. `!($scope.filter.list.searchBy == 'GROUP' && !$scope.filterScope.editorGroups) && ($scope.filter.list.searchBy != 'GROUP')`
2. `($scope.filter.list.searchBy != 'GROUP' || $scope.filterScope.editorGroups) && ($scope.filter.list.searchBy != 'GROUP')`
3. `($scope.filter.list.searchBy != 'GROUP')`

In step 2, I applied [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to simplify `!(A && B)` to `(!A || !B)`.
In step 3, I simplified the `&&`, since `(A || B) && A` is the same as just `A`.

So really, all we know when we enter the `else if` block is that `searchBy != 'GROUP'`. We do not know *anything* about `editorGroups`, and indeed, it may be `undefined`!

What you're *probably* looking for is:

```
if ($scope.filter.list.searchBy == 'GROUP' || !$scope.filterScope.editorGroups) {
    $scope.loadEditorGroups();
} else if ($scope.filter.list.searchBy != 'GROUP') {
    $scope.filter.list.groupId = $scope.filterScope.editorGroups[0].id;
}
```

Notice the `||` in the `if` condition. This ensures that the `else if` is executed only when `($scope.filter.list.searchBy != 'GROUP' && $scope.filterScope.editorGroups)`, so that `editorGroups[0]` will not give an error. I don't know enough if this is what you *intended* this code to do, so correct me when I'm wrong. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`70:81` means *line 70, character 81*.

The problem is at `editorGroups[0]`: If `editorGroups` is `undefined`, it cannot read `editorGroups[0]` because `undefined` has no property called `0`.

Make sure that `editorGroups` isn't undefined and you'll be fine!